Get sibling and parents with recursive SQL Server query
I have this table



Id
ParentId




1
NULL


2
1


3
1


4
NULL


5
4


6
8


7
9



Each child (Id) can have only one parent.
How to retrieve parents and sibling for a given child Id, it means:
SELECT `Here the code`
WHERE Id = 2

Expected result



Id
ParentId




1
NULL


2
1


3
1



For sure I can do something like
select Id, Parentid 
from MyTable
where id = (select ParentId from MyTable where id = 2)
   or ParentId = (select ParentId from MyTable where id = 2)

but it's not very convenient for the rest of my query.
I can also use variables but not convenient too.
I was thinking about recursive query but for the moment without success.
Thanks.

So what's the question???

Your table and your expected result looks exactly the same.

I don't understand the question. Given your sample data and desired results, SELECT * FROM table would suffice. Can you share better sample/desired results that are reflective of your problem. Given the nature of your data, I too suspect that a recursive statement would be the right path, but it's hard to imagine how to write it with your current insufficient sample data.

Search for "adjacency list".

The question is How to retrieve all parents and child for a given Id

@Manta - Your description and example are still not in agreement. Your title includes "get parents". Your description states "all parents and child". However, in your example a starting for id = 2, you show desired results that include id = 1 (parent) and id = 3 (sibling), but omit id = 4 and id = 5 (children). Without a clear and consistent question, your chances of getting an answer are much reduced. Be sure to also clarify if you only want the immediate parent and child rows or all ancestor and descendent rows.  For example, for id = 7, should the results include ids 3 and 1?

@TN you're right, fixed and improved

I do not know what the "rest of my query" looks like, so I will just focus on a couple of alternate ways to program your original query. I have parameterized the starting ID value in both cases.
declare @id int = 2

The following variation uses a join, so that the initial child row is only referenced once.
select R.Id, R.Parentid 
from MyTable C  -- Child
join MyTable R  -- Relative (parent or sibling)
    on R.id = C.ParentId
    or R.ParentId = C.ParentId
where C.id = @id

However, due to the OR condition, the above may cause an unwanted table scan to find both the parent and the siblings. By using a UNION, the parent and sibling lookups are separately optimized to use the appropriate primary key or index. Table or index scans are avoided.
select R.Id, R.Parentid 
from MyTable C  -- Child
cross apply (
    select P.*
    from MyTable P  -- Parent
    where P.id = C.ParentId
    union all
    select S.*
    from MyTable S  -- Sibling
    where S.ParentId = C.ParentId
) R
where C.id = @id

To embed the above into a larger query, you can change the initial from to a join.
select ...
from ...(rest of query)...
join MyTable C  -- Child
    on C.id = ...
...(join or cross apply to "relative" rows here)...
...(rest of query)...

See this db<>fiddle for a demo
